# Simple Ajax Error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm new to AJAX and trying to figure out how to do a JSONP cross-domain call. I'm not exactly sure what is wrong with the following code. In the Firebug NET console I can see the response just fine (full HTML page), and the HTML tab shows up fine also. I'm getting a "syntax error" that's pointing to the URL /?jsonp=jQuery17109722891130251606_1345069208686&_=1345069209298.

I had an error section in there, but just read that error functions inside of the .ajax don't work correctly when using JSONP?

Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    complete:function(jsonp){
    $('#test').append(jsonp);
}
});
```

I'm running this locally, have tried different URLs.... any ideas or explanations? Thanks!
Forgot to mention that the textStatus is also throwing a parsererror?

Comment: Are you sure the server you are making the call to actually supports JSONP?

Comment: INstead of comeplete: use success:

Comment: [What is JSONP?](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)

Comment: jquery API Ajax page talks about JSONP http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Tried success and still get the syntax error, but can still see all of the HTML/page in the NET panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In here

```
complete:function(jsonp){
    $('#test').append(jsonp);
}
```

you are trying to append a `jqXHR` object to a DOM element. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/TkUBz/

What you need to do is to use the `success` property, as in:

```
    /*complete*/
    success:function(data){
        $('#test').append(data);
    }
```

Now, the syntax error that you see is because you're loading `google's` front page, which contains a javascript code, which the browser tries to execute when it appends the HTML data to the `#test` element and that javascript code won't work on your page for different reasons, therefore the code fails and you see a syntax error.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use this? I'm trying to append the information to the page?

Comment: @Aaron, I just gave an example of the `success` property. In your case you should just replace `complete` with `success` in your code.

Comment: Hey Vlad, this won't allow for cross domain. I've tried the exact code both with and without the JSONP info and still receive everything correctly inside of the NET panel, but get the syntax error. As soon as remove the AJAX block no error. Weird

Comment: I explained about the error in the post. Try Firefox, it explains the error a bit more elaborate.